# CASE example when it comes to proper mailing names

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, case

I have the following:

```
Primary                        Spouse
Mr. James Watson               Mrs. Emily Watson
Dr. Janet Snow                 Mr. Todd Snow
Dr. Ben Moody                  Dr. Sarah Farmer
Hon. Ann Lilly                 Dr. Gary Pillars
```

I would like the outcome to be:

```
Combined Mailing Name
Mr. and Mrs. James Watson
Dr. Janet Snow and Mr. Todd Snow
Dr. Ben Moody and Dr. Sarah Farmer
Hon. Ann Lilly and Dr. Gary Pillars
```

Basically following the rules:

- Couple with same last name, equal prefixes, man’s name/info comes first.
- Couple with same last name, greater prefix comes first.
- Couple with different last names, prefix equal or his is greater, man’s name/info comes first.
- Couple with different last names, hers is greater prefix, her name/info comes first.

It's essentially a CASE statement, with loops correct?

Prefix is a separate field.
Thanks.

Comment: Are first and last names separate fields too?

Comment: Hi, yup, they are separate fields as well.

Comment: Are they also in the same row? ie  `Primary_FName`, `Spouse_FName`, ...  and how are the prefixes ranked?

Comment: Yes, same row. Thanks.

Comment: The fields are: prefix, first_name, last_name. I had to do a self-join to find spouse names. It's pretty much just three fields.

Comment: If they only end up on the same row as a result of a self-join, then I'd suggest adding a ranking field for the prefix so you can order them easily.  Adding sample data and hierarchy of prefixes to your question would be helpful.  Also, which database are you using?

Comment: Oracle. SQL Developer.

Comment: Under what circumstances is the secondary person's first name dropped?

Comment: Hi John, when the prefixes are equal (Mr/Mrs) or when the male is a Dr. Usually, it's the secondary female name that gets dropped else both names are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes, a `CASE` expression, but I'm not sure why loops would have any relevance at all.  Are you supposing you would need a stored procedure, or something?

The most important issue appears to be establishing which spouse is the higher ranked.  This can be addressed with the help of an auxiliary table, maybe something like this:

```
create table prefix_rank (
  prefix varchar(4) primary key,
  rank int
);
insert into prefix_rank values ('Mr.',  10);
insert into prefix_rank values ('Mrs.', 10);
insert into prefix_rank values ('Dr.',  20);
insert into prefix_rank values ('Hon.', 30);
```

Note the gaps between rank values.  Leaving gaps allows you to break ties between spouses in favor of the husband by adding a constant smaller than the gap size to the husband's rank.

Note also that I use the prefix itself as the key, instead of introducing a surrogate key.  If you don't already have a separate table of prefixes then this permits the ranking data to be added without reorganizing your existing tables and queries, and it avoids needing to join the prefix table to get prefixes when you want them for any other purpose than mailing labels.

Having that in place, you might query the needed address labels like so ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fab1/10/0)):

```
with ranked_person as (
  select p.*, (pr.rank + (case p.gender WHEN 'M' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END)) AS rank
  from person p join prefix_rank pr on p.prefix = pr.prefix
)
select
  prim.id,
  case
    when sec.id IS NULL then
      prim.prefix || ' ' || prim.first_name || ' ' || prim.last_name 
    when (prim.last_name = sec.last_name and sec.prefix = 'Mrs.') then
      prim.prefix || ' and ' || sec.prefix  || ' '
        || prim.first_name || ' ' || prim.last_name
    else
      prim.prefix || ' ' || prim.first_name || ' ' || prim.last_name || ' and ' ||
      sec.prefix  || ' ' || sec.first_name  || ' ' || sec.last_name
  end as mailing_name
from
  ranked_person prim
  left join ranked_person sec on sec.id = prim.spouse_id
where
  prim.rank > COALESCE(sec.rank, 0)
;
```

Additional things to note:

- Using a left join accommodates obtaining mailing names for unmarried people with the same query
- Filtering for `prim.rank > sec.rank` avoids duplicates, and ensures that table `prim` really contains the info for the higher-ranked (primary) person of each couple
- Having sorted out which is the higher-ranked spouse before reaching the select list of the main query, the needed `CASE` expression for choosing which way to assemble the name isn't bad at all.

Comment: Note: I updated the WHERE condition, which previously dealt incorrectly with unmarried people.